# Can't connect to Redis/Memcache from inside Docker Container

Tags: docker, redis, memcached, docker-machine

I have a Docker Image which encapsulates all the tools for our dev environment. However, running the application in certain profiles will attempt to connect to external Redis/Memcache servers.

However, it can't establish a connection with these servers. When pinging inside the container, it finds the correct IP for the host but it says the host is unreachable:

```
ping HOST
PING HOST (CORRECT.IP) 56(84) bytes of data.
From e856591c01e7 (172.17.0.3) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From e856591c01e7 (172.17.0.3) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From e856591c01e7 (172.17.0.3) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From e856591c01e7 (172.17.0.3) icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From e856591c01e7 (172.17.0.3) icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From e856591c01e7 (172.17.0.3) icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
```

pinging or curling other sites, such as google or facebook, work completely fine.

DockerMachine is the default as are the network settings. Running on Mac OSX 10.10.5, Docker 1.12.1, Docker-Machine 0.8.1

Any ideas? I'm at a loss.

Comment: did you ever solve this problem? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: never solved it, but if i had to guess, it had to do with the docker network bridge and the memcache/redis servers being accessible in private network only. it should've just worked.

Comment: I agree. I think this is an issue with Docker for Mac. The network bridge isn't available. I wasn't able to find a fix. I ended up using a Linux VM.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is using different network modes. You could try to run your container in "Host Network", so it will share the network connections with the host running docker-machine:

```
 docker run --net=host your_image and other options
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this as well and it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem in the future, try making a docker network with ipv6 and the ports open. I didn't get it working but I'm fairly certain that is the right path.

Answer (score 0):

If the possible solutions above don't work. Maybe you should check memcache server config for listened IP addresses.

Is memcache machine another docker container or a seperate standalone server for memcache?

If you wish to connect to the host machine's memcache server, you may need to configure memcache to allow connections from IP addresses other than local IP.

If you are using ubuntu (or similar) edit config with ;

```
nano /etc/memcached.conf
```

and find the line starting with "-l 127.0.0.1" add your client machines IP addresses by separating them with commas.

For instance if you want to connect from 172.17.0.3 and 172.18.0.3 you replace with ;

```
-l 127.0.0.1,172.17.0.1,172.18.0.1
```